# Pathfinder Magus Spellstrike + Spell Combat

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magus

I'm trying to make sure I have this right because I don't want to try something only to be laughed out of the room or lose credibility for attempting to break any rules.

I have an L2 Magus who (obviously) has Spell Combat and Spellstrike. Let's say I use Spell Combat, casting Shocking Grasp and missing with both my attacks (the free touch/weapon attack from the cast/Spellstrike as well as the regular attack) and continue to hold my Shocking Grasp.

Next round, I'm up and I'd like to do the same thing as before, only changed slightly. I want to use Spell Combat, attacking first and casting later. So, let's say I hit with my normal attack and deliver my Shocking Grasp through my weapon, discharging my held spell via Spellstrike. I've spent that, but Spell Combat shows I can now cast a touch spell (to be easy, let's do Shocking Grasp again), which can in turn be delivered with another attack via Spellstrike. We're looking at 1d8(longsword)+2(str) + 2d6(shocking grasp) + 1d8(longsword)+2(str) + 2d6(shocking grasp); an average of 27, which will easily one-shot a lot of CR2 and lower monsters (let alone myself).

Is this previous paragraph an accurate description of what I can do? I know at least one person at my table that would scream about how ridiculous those two rounds would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spellstrike(Su)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus#TOC-Spellstrike-Su-) States:

> At 2nd level, whenever a magus casts a spell with a range of “touch”
>   from the magus spell list, he can deliver the spell through any weapon
>   he is wielding as part of a melee attack. **Instead of the free melee
>   touch attack normally allowed to deliver the spell, a magus can make
>   one free melee attack with his weapon (at his highest base attack
>   bonus) as part of casting this spell.**

If you missed while you had a charge of Shocking Grasp and that spell wasn't discharged, on the following round you can use an action to attack to discharge the spell and another action to cast another spell, which gives you a bonus attack. There's also a Caveat with Full Round Magus actions that I believe would be of interest to you as well:

From [Spell Combat(Ex)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus#TOC-Spell-Combat-Ex-):

> As a full-round action, he can make all of his attacks with his melee weapon at a –2 penalty and can also cast any spell from the
>   magus spell list with a casting time of 1 standard action (any attack
>   roll made as part of this spell also takes this penalty).

This meaning that at higher levels you would get multiple attacks as well as the bonus attack you get from Spellstrike after casting a spell as well.

Comment: I'm confused. Why would they get a free attack in round 2?

Comment: With Spell Combat you can "Two weapon fighting" with magic and a sword. Your full attack action gives you an attack, and lets you cast a spell which triggers spellstrike, giving you another attack to discharge the spell.

If you miss with your charge on round one, you still have it at the end of round one. So you use full attack, attack once to discharge the current touch spell, and then cast it again using Spellstrike.

Comment: Ah, I see. I wasn't seeing the full attack.

Answer (score 0):

After reading both abilities for the Magus, you are correct.

> A Magus can make one free melee attack with his weapon (at his highest base attack bonus) as part of casting this spell

If other players want to be upset about this, remind them that it still consumes one of your spells so its not like your able to do this every round.

Comment: Arcane Mark is a contact spell of level 0, so you could do it every turn. Not really useful if you cast then move in range (it's just a standard attack) but with Spell Combat, it gives you a bonus attack to your full-attack for a global -2 attack penalty. I do think it's OP (especially at low level and combined with Arcana pool's enchantment) but it seem legal RAW-wise.